# Why my system sometimes forgets the environment variables

Tags: environment-variables

Sometimes (I cannot locate better: may happen when I am developing, may happen in two weeks or so after several on/offs) my system forgets the environmental variables I set. (i.e. 'echo' display empty string). I 'export' the variable again, and it runs again for a while. I have no idea why is happens and whether I can avoid it.

Comment: Are you talking of the system ones or custom ones?

Comment: Which variables, only the system variables, only the user defined variables or both? Where and how did you define this variables?

Comment: I experienced it with user-defined variables, which I define in a terminal window, using 'export'.

Comment: I think now I can locate better my question. I am using QCreator, and sometimes I need to 'Clear CMake configuration'. It looks like this command deletes my environmental variables, too. Shall it? Another experience: When I re-export my variables in a terminal window, then start QCreator again, it is still missing the variables. After I make a cmake ..; make, QCreator  can build my project OK. Till now I guessed that QCreator is just a GUI for those command-line tools. It is not so?